# why jpg file are saved as tmp in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to upload image in admin panel. but this image is uploading as tmp.

Need I add something other code in my code?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('contents')) {
        $destinationPath = 'pictures/SliderImages';
        $files = $request->contents;
        $file_name = $files->getClientOriginalName();
        $files->move($destinationPath, $file_name);
        echo "Complete";
    } else {
        echo "No File";
    }

    $inputs = $request->all();
    $sliders = Sliders::Create($inputs);
    return redirect()->action('SliderController@index');
}
```

this is my blade:

```
                @foreach($sliders as $slider)
                    <tr>
                <td>{{$slider->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$slider->title}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{$slider->contents}}"></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

[this is result in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVrvO.png)

Comment: You need a filename in the destination path, not just a directory name

Comment: Is the file actually moved as you expect? I.e. is the file moved incorrectly too, or is it just the path in your DB that is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$inputs = $request->all(); 
$inputs['contents'] = $file_name;    // add this line in your code

$sliders = Sliders::Create($inputs);
return redirect()->action('SliderController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$inputs` you pass in to `Sliders::Create` looks to be the original `$request` parameters? Which probably doesn't include the adjustments you made to that uploaded file.